# Best way to find the middle element/index used in Searching & Sorting Algorithms?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search, mergesort

As we know there are various ways to get the middle element/index for a given sub-array(during recursive calls). Also we have to take care of overflow, large value of low/high condition as well, so which one should we prefer?

**Method 1**

```
mid = (low + high) / 2
```

**Method 2**

```
mid = low + (high - low) / 2
```

Comment: This depends on language. In Python and many other languages you don't need to worry about overflow so the CPython builtin [uses `mid = (low + high) // 2`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/bisect.py#L31). The third option you present is logically wrong. See [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80415/why-is-binary-search-using-this-weird-thing-to-calculate-middle) on CS.SE.

Comment: @ggorlen yes, third is wrong, its a mistake, sorry for that...:)

Answer (score 0):

The third option is logically wrong. Both the first option and second option are logically correct but the first method can lead you to `integer overflow`. So, your second method is more appropriate to use.